# Upload to App Store Failed: No Version Found for 'adamId - platform'

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, xcode7

I am trying to submit an app update for an iOS app to support devices running iOS 9, and in the process of uploading to the App Store via XCode, I'm getting the following error:

[image]

No version found for 'adamId - platform' (936823648-Mac OS X App).  If this problem persists for more than 24 hours, please contact your Apple representative.

This is an iOS app, not an OS X App, so I don't know why I am getting this error.  I have already submitted several versions of the app to the App Store previously.

Anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved the problem by submitting the app using Application Loader instead of uploading via XCode.  Seems like it might be an issue with XCode 7?

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_3.0.dmg

Comment: I have the same problem, but it is not solved by using Application Loader. This is with Xcode 7.0.1

Comment: As Rick Pasveer points out, the 3.0 version of Application Loader seems to be essential to making this work.

Comment: @scientiffic Were you able to upload using Xcode lately? I am facing similar issue.

Comment: I am having Xcode version 7.3.1 & Loader (3.5) still i producing this error since last more than 24 hours. 

Now how to get resolve?I tried more than 10 times with updated xcode version.

Answer (score 6):

As @scientiffic says in his answer. You should use Application Loader to upload your app. I thought using ANY version of Application Loader would solve this problem but no.

You need Application Loader 3.0 version. It doesn't work if you use Application Loader 3.2.

Comment: @rick Were you able to upload using Xcode lately? I am facing similar issue.

Comment: version 3.1 works fine for me using Xcode 7.1.1 exported archives

Comment: I get the same problem with Application Loader 3.4. I guess I'll use one of my 2 annual support calls and see what they say  :(

Answer (score 5):

I realize this is an old question, but I have had this problem for about a year with no resolution from Apple. I had been using an old version of Application Loader as a solution to this problem, like many others, until I ran into a complication (I have one Apple ID that is attached to multiple iTunes Connect accounts and older versions of Application Loader do not support this). Essentially, I had to find a solution that allows me to use newer versions of Application Loader/Xcode to submit binaries or I was dead in the water.

It turns out I had a key in my Info.plist that was Mac OS X specific. LSMinimumSystemVersion or “Minimum system version”. Removing that key from the Info.plist solved the adamid - platform error.

Answer (score 5):

Just for the record - this error message also comes if you are trying to upload an app for a wrong platform - e.g. uploading an iOS app with a bundle id that is registered as a tvOS app on iTunes Connect.
You can use tvOS/iOS with identical app ids (for e.g. universal in-app purchases), but both platforms must be enabled manually on iTunes Connect, or you will get this cryptic error (at least true in XCode 8).

Comment: Happened to me with Xcode 9, tried uploading Mac App to iOS ID. Thanks!

Comment: Happened to me right now in Xcode 9.4.1 — I built the app with the wrong Bundle Identifier.

Answer (score 2):

Saw this when the tvOS version did not exist on the App Store.

Answer (score 2):

I fix that by adding a 1.0 version to tvOS APP as the screenshot.

[image: App Store Connect]

Answer (score 1):

Same problem with Application Loader 3.5.

Downloaded 3.0 as mentioned and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You might get this error if you haven't set up iTunes Correctly to accept an app upload.  I.e. its possible you haven't created an app with the matching bundle id within iTunes Connect.