# Submitting to itune app store showing error

Tags: ios, app-store

I am getting error on uploading the iOS app on itune . Error Message shows like this -

```
"no version found for admld plateform (1207202682- mac os x app).
```

If this problem persist more than 24 hours then please contact apple representative"

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659970/upload-to-app-store-failed-no-version-found-for-adamid-platform

Comment: this is not working inmy case . i have xcode 7.2 and mac os x 10.11.3. and also tried with application loader 3.0; but it is not working .

Answer (score 0):

Try to upload your app with Application Loader.I solved the problem by submitting the app using Application Loader instead of uploading via XCode. Seems like it might be an issue with XCode?

Comment: my question is same . but the solotutions provided by users are not relevant . after applying these  changes . again i am getting same error .

Comment: @Krishanvirsingh try to upload app with different xcode version

Comment: i got the answer  .i tried with application loader 3.1 . it is working for me . i also tried with 3.0 , 3.2 ,3.4 latest verison . but it was not working .

Comment: Yes krishan it works for application loader with 3.1 version.